# Angular Map and mergeMap rxjs6 operators

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6

Newbie question:

I am trying to export my data from a rest API to firebase.

I am using **Angular6** with **RxJS 6**.

```
getByTag(tag:string) {
  return this.http.get(this.URL + '/get/listings/', { headers })
    .pipe(
      map((res: Listings) => res.items),
      // How do I add an additional property to each of these items? eg res.items.inserted = new Date();
      // How do chain each of these res.items to another function called exportToFirebase(res.item))
    );
}
```

My Data looks something like this:
https://pasteboard.co/HWp1hUb.jpg

I tried the map function but my incoming data stream from the API is an array of arrays so 
I attempted mergeMap without any success
(https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

I attempted a `do()` statement to trigger the `exportToFirebase(res.item)`, but It looks like I am completely off track here :-P

**Expected result:** Create a loop to send  item parameter of type Listing to my service function called `exportToFirebase(res.item)`

**Questions?**

1. How do I add an additional property to each of these items? eg `res.items.inserted = new Date();` ?
2. How do chain each of these `res.items` to another function called `exportToFirebase(res.item))` ?

Comment: So your problem is that `exportToFirebase(res.item)` returns an Observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mergeMap` is useless in your case because it was created for flattening observables.

So `map` operator should do all the job.

```
getByTag(tag:string) {
  return this.http.get(this.URL + '/get/listings/', { headers })
    .pipe(
      map((res: Listings) => res.items),
      map((list: any[]) => {
        return list.map(sublist => sublist.map(item => {...item, inserted: new Date()}));
      })
    );
}
```

**Update**

You can flatten your array using `reduce`:

```
map((res: Listings) => res.items.reduce(((arr, list) => arr.concat(list), [])),

map((list: any[]) => {
  return list.map(item => {...item, inserted: new Date()});
})
```

To chain you can use `do`/`tap`:

```
tap((list: any[]) => {
  list.forEach(item => {
    exportToFirebase(item)
  });
})
```

So the actual execution of `exportToFirebase` is on your side, Idk what the signature of that function if it returns Observable or smth

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right and you want to add a field to each item in the results array then pass each one individually to the exportToFirebase() function, then something like this could be of use:

```
getByTag(tag:string) {
  return this.http.get(this.URL + '/get/listings/', { headers })
    .pipe(
      map((res: Listings) => res.items)
    )
    .subscribe(items => {
      items.forEach(i => {
        i.inserted = new Date();

        exportToFirebase(i);
      });
    });
}
```

You can also use the [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) operator, as another answer mentioned, if you don't want to use subscribe.